# Issues setting up YoloV3 on MacOs

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet

I am trying to test out object detection on a video I have but ran into this issue

```
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

So I changed OPENCV=1 in the Makefile but ran into this error now

```
./src/image_opencv.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

OpenCV works on my laptop for both Xcode and VSCode so I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What is the opencv version you are using ? Can you run this on terminal ```pkg-config --modversion opencv```

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk it shows 2.x.x and when I try pkg-config --modversion opencv4 it says 4.3.0. Could me having both of them be the problem?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk also I have no issue using opencv on Xcode for my object detection project.

Comment: yolov3 works for opencv 3.4.2 or higher. You cant have 2 versions of opencv at the same time. If you try to install opencv before uninstalling previous one it will occur some problems. My suggestion is clear opencv and install again. *Note:* I might be wrong

Comment: How do i uninstall Opencv 2.x.x? Since its not a specific version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was fixed by setting the path to the absolute path of the model weights and model configuration files.